# how do you access to a pivot table in pandas to fill nan values in the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have an original data frame with information from real estate properties. To fill nan values in the column price per m2 in usd I have made a multi-index pivot table that has the mean of the price per m2 sliced by property type, place and surface covered in m2. 
Now, I want to iterate in the original data frame´s column price per m2 in usd to fill nan values with the ones I created in the pivot table.

Pivot table code:

```
df6 = df4.pivot_table( values=['price_usd_per_m2'], 
                       index=['cuartiles_superficie_cubierta'],
                       columns=['localidad','property_type'], 
                       aggfunc=['mean'])
```

Comment: You have given some code, which is a good thing. But you should also give a data sample so the other could reproduce. As a new user, you should read [ask] and specificaly the part about [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my understanding is correct or not, do you mind to show how does your data table look like? Based on your question, you have done the calculation on mean values, and you wish to replace the NaN in the original table before pivoted.

Possible if you fill up NaN with the mean values in the pivoted table, then only transform back to the original structure as you wish?

[image]
[image]

Apologize if my answer not helping, I just wish to learn how to solving problem. I will also learn from other who giving advise on this question.